# Devise generate view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, rvm

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.rubyonrailstree.blogspot.com/2014/02/ruby-on-rails-device-gem-install-step.html

and I am having trouble with:

```
rails g devise:views
```

&

```
rake db:migrate
```

both comming up with a simmilar error of:

```
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `attr_accessible' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/app/models/user.rb:8:in `<class:User>'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise.rb:259:in `get'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/mapping.rb:103:in `to'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/mapping.rb:98:in `modules'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/mapping.rb:115:in `routes'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/mapping.rb:84:in `initialize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise.rb:289:in `new'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise.rb:289:in `add_mapping'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:190:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:189:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-1.4.7/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:189:in `devise_for'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Am I using version of ruby that does not support this yet?  I will keep looking into this error and I thank anyone who has information about this issue.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users


 root 'home#index'



user.rb model:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
   :email
   :password
   :password_confirmation
   :remember_me
end
```

thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: post the user model and routes please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `root 'home#index'` should be changed `root to: "home#index"`.
2. Starting from Rails 4 you do not use `attr_accessible`. You will have to remove the line.
3. when using a gem the better solution is to appeal to its [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). So in your case the command to generate views (after you added `gem 'devise'` to `Gemfile` and run `bundle`) should be

a) `rails generate devise:install`,

b) `rails generate devise:views`

Comment: just delete the attr_accessible and leave the rest?=D

Comment: yeah, check this out https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters. Strong_parameters gem is now a part of rails. You will have to define the user_params method in users_controller. Oh, cool!

Comment: However, when I rake db:migrate it is not getting updated, do I need to do rake db:migrate:redo?

Comment: what is not getting updated? did you run  rails g devise user?

Comment: yes I have the user model, my pg database is not getting updated.

Comment: what is the output of rake:db migrate?

Comment: I will post my current model, I am guessing that's where its wrong.  Updating above

Comment: if there is no errors in as an output this means that problem is somewhere else. Try to spend sometime digging (check the link I provided earlier in comments) and I am sure you'll find something!